# NancyFX : Why is my IUserMapper singleton instantiated twice?

Tags: singleton, forms-authentication, nancy

I am trying to implement a very simple example of FormsAuthentication. It is not real life but it has thrown up a problem. The AuthenticationService, which is intended to be an Application level singleton, appears to be instantiated twice.

Here is the code:

```
public class User : IUserIdentity
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Claims { get; set; }
}

public interface IAuthenticationService
{
    Guid GetIdentifier(string username, string password);
}

public class AuthenticationService : IUserMapper, IAuthenticationService
{
    public readonly Guid Identifier = Guid.NewGuid();
    private readonly string Username = "admin";
    private readonly string Password = "x";

    public Guid GetIdentifier(string username, string password)
    {
        return (username == Username && password == Password) ? Identifier : Guid.Empty;
    }

    public IUserIdentity GetUserFromIdentifier(Guid identifier, NancyContext context)
    {
        return (identifier == Identifier) ? new User { UserName = "admin" } : null;
    }
}

public class MyBootstrapper : DefaultNancyBootstrapper
{
    protected override void ConfigureApplicationContainer(TinyIoCContainer container)
    {
        base.ConfigureApplicationContainer(container);
        container.Register<IAuthenticationService, AuthenticationService>().AsSingleton();
    }
}
```

The code above is being used by my `LoginModule` as follows. Please note that I am injecting the application-level singleton instance of the `AuthenticationService` via the module's constructor.

```
public LoginModule(IAuthenticationService authenticationService)
{
    Post["/login"] = _ =>
    {
        var identifier = authenticationService.GetIdentifier(
            (string) Form.Username, 
            (string) Form.Password);

        if (identifier.IsEmpty())
        {
            return Context.GetRedirect("~/login?error=true");
        }
        return this.LoginAndRedirect(identifier);
    };
}
```

What should happen is that when the user `POSTs` their username and password, these are checked by the `AuthenticationService` via the `GetIdentifier(..)` method. If the credentials match then the single `GUID` identifier is returned. This `GUID` will always be the same because it is created as a `readonly` field and thus set once when the singleton `AuthenticationService` is first instantiated at application startup.

However this is not the case. Instead two distinct instances of the `AuthenticationService` are created, one that is injected into the `LoginModule` constructor and used to call the `GetIdentifier(..)` method and another instance which Nancy uses to call the `IUserIdentity.GetUserFromIdentifier(..)` method.

These two instances have different `GUID` identifiers and so the `GetUserFromIdentifier(..)` method always return null.

I have tested a standard singleton service that does not implement `IUserMapper` and it works as expected, only one instance is created.

So it seems that Nancy is instantiating the `IUserMapper` singleton twice, once for its own internal use during FormsAuthentication, and once to inject into my `LoginModule` constructor!

Can you spot my mistake?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because you're using a different interface so you have one singleton for things requesting IUsernameMapper and another for things requesting IAuthenticationService.

You can either:

- Register both with an instance of your authentication service
- Split out the username mapper and take a dependency on that in your service (so your Application Service has a dependency on the IUsernameMapper - that will be the same one Nancy is using)
- Register one of them using a factory that resolves using the other interface (container.Register((c,p) => c.Resolve

My I ask why you're doing any of this though rather than just using the built in forms auth?

Comment: I thought I _was_ using the built in Forms Authentication :-) Is this not the way to do it? The example above is meant to provide me with a very quick, single user sign-in to secure a single admin page (I don't have a data-store and don't want to create one for just one user). Can you point me to an explanation or, better, provide a quick code example here please. Thanks.